# Threads in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm updating my C++ skills to C++11.  I'm up to threads, always a problem area.  Consider this testing code:

```
// threaded.h
class MyThreadedClass
{
public:
    MyThreadClass();
    bool StartThread();
    bool IsThreadDone();
    inline void WorkThread();

private:
    std::thread* workThread;
    atomic<bool> threadDone;
}

// threaded.cpp
MyThreadedClass::MyThreadedClass() {
    workThread = nullptr;
    threadDone.store(true);
}

bool MyThreadedClass::StartThread() {
    if (!threadDone.load()) { return false; }
    threadDone.store(false);
    workThread = new std::thread(&MyThreadedClass:WorkThread, this);
    workThread->detach();
    return true;
}

bool MyThreadedClass:IsThreadDone() {
    return threadDone.load();
}

inline void MyThreadedClass::WorkThread() {
    while (some_condition) { /*Do work*/ }
    threadDone.store(true);
}

// main.cpp
int main() {
    MyThreadedClass testInstance;
    testInstance.StartThread();
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        do {
            // This is sometimes true:
            if (testInstance.StartThread()) { return 1;}
        } while (!testInstance.IsThreadDone())
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to look at a worst case scenario for this type of code therefore I'm pounding it continually in main while waiting for thread to terminate.  Sometimes the failure condition in main is triggered.  As with many threading problems it's not consistent and therefore not easy to debug.

The threadDone variable is used because I access a file in my actual code and don't want multiple threads accessing the same file.

Insight into what I'm missing or ways to redesign this with C++11 idioms welcome.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. Are you getting results you did not expect? What are they exactly. The way I see it, your code should always get to the if inside the do while statement unless there is some exception thrown.

Comment: The condition in _StartThread_ looks strange. Each time you invoke the function, a new _thread_ is created, if no thread has reached `threadDone.store(true)` yet. I don't understand it.

Comment: What exactly does it test?

Comment: I guess `workThread = new std::thread(&MyClass:WorkThread, this);` should be `workThread = new std::thread(&MyClass::WorkThread, this);` not that it has anything to do with anything :)

Comment: The problem: the condition in the do-while loop in main is sometimes true.  Meaning, it successfully starts a new thread while an existing thread is running, which is not what I want.

Comment: Apologies, I transcribed some of the code wrongly.  Code should be right now.

Comment: At "// Code sometimes gets here.", of course it gets there, it's at the beginning of a for loop with no control flow to branch away.

Comment: @JeffreyYasskin Yes, I mean the conditional on next line is sometimes true. I updated comment to make that clearer. The problem is threading not control flow.

Comment: @Haruspex then what's the issue? You checked `while (!testInstance.IsThreadDone())` it evaluated to true, then your threads switched, the work finished, threadDone is set to true, now the thread goes back to you main thread that has already decided it's going to execute the code block in the do while. Btw. if you're afraid of the overhead of mutexes then you should be even more afraid of the overhead of busy waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With *std::mutex* instead of *std::atomic*, the implementation is quite simple.

```
class MyThreadedClass
{
    std::mutex _mutex;
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> _thread;
    bool _done{false};
public:
    MyThreadClass() = default;
    bool StartThread()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        if (_thread || _done) return false;
        _thread = std::make_unique<std::thread>(&MyThreadedClass, this);
        return true;
    }
    bool IsThreadDone()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        return _done;
    }
    void WorkThread()
    {
        // do some work
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        _done = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for example. I avoided mutex because of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The best reference / learning book I know of for C++11 concurrency is here: [C++ Concurrency in Action: Practical Multithreading](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988770) by Anthony Williams.

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition (though not a "data race") in your `main()` function, which I've transcribed, inlined, and simplified below:

```
void MyThreadedClass::WorkThread() {
    threadDone.store(true);
}

int main() {
    MyThreadedClass testInstance;
    testInstance.threadDone.store(false);
    new std::thread(&MyThreadedClass::WorkThread, &testInstance)->detach();
    // This sometimes fails:
    assert(!testInstance.threadDone.load());
    return 0;
}
```

That assertion will fail if WorkThread happens to run to completion before the main thread is scheduled again. Since the standard doesn't constrain the scheduling, you'd need to write some code to block if you need the worker thread to wait.